# Ant Script importPackage does not work after upgrading to ant 1.9.2

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, rhino

just upgraded to eclipse luna which contains ant 1.9.2 and my `<script>` targets stopped working in this code:

```
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    importPackage(java.net);
    importPackage(java.io);
    ...
```

error message:

```
 javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "importPackage" is not defined in <eval> at line number 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of Java are you running? [Rhino has been replaced](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/174) in Java 8.

The following bug might be the problem: [JDK-8025132](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025132).